# Form not submitting when I load it with ng-view

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I have configured the angularjs file so that the view is loaded when i press on the 'add item' button in the navigation bar, however when I try submitting the form nothing happens. But if I load the php file separately it works without any problems and adds the data to my json file.

**MY HTML**

```
<head>

    <title></title>

    <link href="almstyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="Framework/css/mycss.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="Framework/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="Framework/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Framework/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Start of header -->
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <h4 id="banner">LOGO</h4>
                </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of header -->

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header navbar-left">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#!home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="hairtab.html">Hair</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!cart">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="News.html">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!addItem">Add Item</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">LifeStyle <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Passion</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>

          </div>

        </nav>

        <div data-ng-view></div>

    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="home/home.js"></script>
    <script src="addItem/addItem.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**My Php Template**

```
    <?php  
 $message = '';  
 $error = '';  
 if(isset($_POST["submit"]))  
 {  
      if(empty($_POST["item"]))  
      {  
           $error = "<label class='text-danger'>Enter Item Name</label>";  
      }  
      else if(empty($_POST["id"]))  
      {  
           $error = "<label class='text-danger'>Enter Item Id</label>";  
      }  
      else if(empty($_POST["size"]))  
      {  
           $error = "<label class='text-danger'>Enter a size for your item</label>";  
      }
      else if(empty($_POST["price"]))  
      {  
           $error = "<label class='text-danger'>Enter a suitable price for the item</label>";  
      } 
      else  
      {  
           if(file_exists('items.json'))  
           {  
                $current_data = file_get_contents('items.json');  
                $array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);  
                $extra = array(  
                     'item'            =>     $_POST['item'],  
                     'id'          =>     $_POST["id"],  
                     'selected'     =>     $_POST["selected"],
                     'prices' => [[
                     'size' => $_POST["size"],
                     'price' => $_POST["price"]

                     ]]
                );  
                $array_data[] = $extra;  
                $final_data = json_encode($array_data);  
                if(file_put_contents('items.json', $final_data))  
                {  
                     $message = "<label class='text-success'>The Item has been added successfully</p>";
                }  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                $error = 'JSON File does not exist';  
           }  
      }  
 }  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
  <head>  
       <title>Add items</title>  
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  </head>  
  <body>  
       <br />  
       <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  
            <h3 align="">Add items</h3><br />                 
            <form method="post">  
                 <?php   
                 if(isset($error))  
                 {  
                      echo $error;  
                 }  
                 ?>  
                 <br />  
                 <label>Item Name</label>  
                 <input type="text" name="item" class="form-control" /><br />  
                 <label>Item Id</label>  
                 <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" />
                <input type="hidden" name="selected" value="0" class="form-control" hidden="hidden"/><br />
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel panel-heading">
                        Prices
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-body">
                        <label>Size</label>
                        <input type="text" name="size" class="form-control" />

                        <label>Price</label>
                        <input type="number" name="price" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                     <br /> 
                </div>

                 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Item" class="btn btn-info" /><br />                      
                 <?php  
                 if(isset($message))  
                 {  
                      echo $message;  
                 }  
                 ?>  
            </form>  
       </div>  
       <br />  
  </body>
```

**This is what it should look like after submitting**
[image]

Comment: i don't see where you've set the form ctrl or the app name?

Comment: Ah.... weird how it didn't add that when i copy pasted the code. ng-app was in the <html> tag and for this form I didn't use any controller that's why its not there in the template! I only used angularjs to route! :)

Comment: I only saw your comment now, I was writing an answer. Just noticed you already accepted. Oh well.. it looked like you had a form already at the end but it was just set up incorrectly? no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few  mistakes here ,

1. I don't see a form with the action attribute set as path to php resource.
2. For a form to submit, you should have a button of type submit. Some thing like this.

> ```
> <html>
> <body>
>
> <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
> Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
> E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
> <input type="submit">
> </form>
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

And your PHP file can be

> ```
> <html>
> <body>
>
> Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
> Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

I hope this helps you to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

For a form to work "the angular way", you need a couple to specify a couple of extra bits.

You'll firstly need the name the `ng-app` after the opening html tag to indicate that the that block of code will be 'watched' by an angular module (which you will specify also in the code).

You'll also need to add an `ng-controller` tag to the form which you will name and then refer to in your javascript

In the angular form , add an `ng-click` to send it to submit the form if the form validates successfully: `ng-click=”formsubmit(userForm.$valid)”`

Here is some [sample code](http://shabeebk.com/blog/simple-form-submit-in-angularjs-with-php/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="formExample">
    <head>
        <title>simple form with AngualrJS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="js/angular.js" ></script>
        <script src="js/formjs.js"></script>
    </head> 

    <body>

        <div ng-controller="formCtrl">
            <form  name="userForm"  class="well form-search"   >

                <input type="text" ng-model="name" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Name" required >
                <input type="email" ng-model="email" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Email" required >
                <input type="text" ng-model="message" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Message" required >
                <button type="submit" class="btn" ng-click="formsubmit(userForm.$valid)"  ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Submit </button>

            </form>
            <pre ng-model="result">
                {{result}}
            </pre>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>

 JS:
<pre class="lang:default decode:true " title="formjs.js" >
/**
 * @filesource : formjs.js
 * @author : Shabeeb  <mail@shabeebk.com>
 * @abstract : controller fo HTML page
 * @package sample file 
 * @copyright (c) 2014, Shabeeb
 * shabeebk.com/blog
 * 
 *  */
var app = angular.module('formExample', []);
app.controller("formCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.url = 'submit.php';
        $scope.formsubmit = function(isValid) {


            if (isValid) {
                $http.post($scope.url, {"name": $scope.name, "email": $scope.email, "message": $scope.message}).
                        success(function(data, status) {
                            console.log(data);
                            $scope.status = status;
                            $scope.data = data;
                            $scope.result = data; 
                        })
            }else{            
                  alert('Form is not valid');
            }
        }
    }]);</pre> 

 submit:

<?php
/**
 * @filesource : submit.php
 * @author : Shabeeb  <mail@shabeeb.com>
 * @abstract : simple submission php form
 * @package sample file 
 * @copyright (c) 2014, Shabeeb
 * 
 * 
 *  */

$post_date = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($post_date);


//saving to database
//save query

//now i am just printing the values
echo "Name : ".$data->name."n";
echo "Email : ".$data->email."n";
echo "Message : ".$data->message."n";



?>
```

Comment: This gave me a very good idea to improve upon the form. Thank you very much <3